# How to extract a portion between the first and second occurrence of a character using regular expressions in R?

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I need to extract the UniProt IDs between the first and second occurrence of | from the rows 5 to 14 only.

Expected outcome:

```
A0A3Q8IUE6
A4I9M8
E9BQL4
Q4Q3E9
A0A640KX53
E9B4M7
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `strsplit` here with an `apply` function:

```r
df$output <- sapply(df$x, function(x) strsplit(x, "\\|")[[1]][2])
df

                  x     output
1 A|A0A3Q8IUE6|blah A0A3Q8IUE6
2      B|A4I9M8|meh     A4I9M8
```

**Data:**

```
x <- "A|A0A3Q8IUE6|blah"
y <- "B|A4I9M8|meh"
df <- data.frame(x=c(x,y))
```

Note: If certain `x` values in the data frame would not be in pipe-delimited format, and therefore would not have a second element, then `output` might get assigned to the original value.  If you wanted some other behavior, we could use `grepl` to detect, e.g.

```r
df$output <- ifelse(grepl("^(?:tr|sp)\\|", df$x),
                    sapply(df$x, function(x) strsplit(x, "\\|")[[1]][2]),
                    NA)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but then it extracts the pattern from row 1 also, which is not intended. Is there a way to specify that the code should check only the entries starting with 'tr' or 'sp' (as the first | is preceded only by 'tr' or 'sp' in my dataframe). Can functions like sub/gsub or PERL-like regular expressions be used instead?

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury Sure, no problem.  Check the updated bottom half of my answer.  We can use `grepl` in this case.